# Scanned architectural building plans

Tags: data-request, images, city

I am trying to collect architectural buildings plans for some computer vision project. Many cities publish scanned house plans as a service to the public, but it is not standard and not trivial to collect.

Is there a large dataset of scanned plans? It does not have to be of houses for sales or from a specific place. Alternatively, are there open data services of house plans that would be easy to sample from?

Comment: Aw, dude! You have the [coolest user name](https://xkcd.com/327/) evah !!

Answer (score 4):

[Guggenheim Helsinki Design Competition](http://designguggenheimhelsinki.org/en/) opened all of its [entries on GitHub](https://github.com/Guggenheim-Helsinki).
Not sure how many are of houses and/or if this is useful.
[More info here](https://www.guggenheim.org/blogs/checklist/open-architecture-five-points-on-why-we-are-opening-the-guggenheim-helsinki-competition-data-2)

The Open Architecture Network seems to not exist anymore, but the wayback machine has much of it saved. [Here's one example of plans you can access](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20131112021713/http://openarchitecturenetwork.org:80/node/5984/oanattachments).

Answer (score 2):

[Plan N Design](https://www.planndesign.com) has a huge database of residential and commercial building plans. Hope it helps!

Comment: A great site, thanks!! But, can you point out where it says that the plans are Open?